# Magento 2 How to set custom data / option in a quote item?

Tags: magento

I would like to add some data into the quote item, not product.
my approach now is

```
$quoteItems = $this->cart->getItems();
foreach ($quoteItems as $eachQuoteItem) {
    $eachQuoteItem->setCustomname('aaaa');
    $eachQuoteItem->setIsSuperMode(true);
    $eachQuoteItem->save();
};
```

I can use $eachQuoteItem->getCustomname(); to get back 'aaaa' in the same page, but i can not get the data in other request.

any suggestion?
thanks

Comment: You can achieve by a plugin and observer in Magento 2.2.* [Here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/210213/cant-retrieve-custom-option-from-order-items/224529#224529)

Answer (score 1):

The answers provided address the task of converting the quote items to order items.  But, it sounds like you're asking how to set the data on the quote item in the first place.

You can do this by:

a) get items from quote using `getAllVisibleItems()`,
b) call `setData('field', val)` on each item.
c) set updated items on quote using `setItems(items)`
d) then, save the quote

Answer (score 0):

It's late but possibly you need to create plugin for such case as suggested [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/178391/58478).

Comment: I have designed an image from the product page, I need to show on quote and order page, how can I do that with the help of a plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can save custom field value in `quote_item` table by following below,

Create `ModuleName/CompanyName/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item">
        <plugin name="to_save_custom_field_to_quote_item" type="ModuleName\CompanyName\Plugin\ToQuoteItem" />
    </type>    
</config>
```

Create `ModuleName\CompanyName\Plugin\ToQuoteItem.php`

```
<?php
namespace ModuleName\CompanyName\Plugin;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item;

    class ToQuoteItem
    {
    
        public function afterBeforeSave(Item $subject)
        {
            $subject->setCustomField("YOUR_VALUE");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have added select option for each and every item in cart. How can I get that value and save per item respectively